# All drawn shapes are converted to black after cvWriteFrame()

Tags: c++, opencv

So I am drawing color shapes(green, red and white) to ***frame*** in a video. Everything works great. But if I want to write frames into VideoWriter, all these shapes in a ***frame*** are converted to black. Here is my code:

```
CvVideoWriter *new_writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("video.avi",CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 30, Size(640, 480), 1); 
IplImage new_img;

while(!frame.empty()){

    //My code
    imshow("Frame", frame);

    new_img = frame.operator IplImage();  
    int ret = cvWriteFrame(new_writer, (const IplImage*)&new_img);

}
cvReleaseVideoWriter(&new_writer);
```

The problem here is line with ***cvWriteFrame()***. After this, all shapes are converted to black. They are displayed as black in a new ***frame*** and in created video they are also black.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing codec from **CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')**  to **CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V')** everything is fine and colors are right.